# unexpected segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have the following function

```
bool Graph::termination_condition() {
    for(int i = 0; i < nodes; i++) {
        // check if any pair of neighbors is using the same color
        //vector<int> neigh_colors;
        //for(int idx = 0; idx < degree(node); idx++) {
            // adjList[node][idx] is the neighbor
            //if( find(neigh_colors.begin(), neigh_colors.end(), node_obj[adjList[node][idx]].l_color) == neigh_colors.end()  )
            //    // not found, add
                //neigh_colors.push_back(node_obj[adjList[node][idx]].l_color);
            //else
            //    return false;
        //}
        // check if the color of the node is used
        //if( find(neigh_colors.begin(), neigh_colors.end(), node_obj[node].l_color) != neigh_colors.end()  )
        //    return false;
        // check if color of node is in conflict list
        //if( node_obj[node].tmp_conf_list.size() )
        //    if( find( node_obj[node].tmp_conf_list.begin(), node_obj[node].tmp_conf_list.end(), node_obj[node].l_color) != node_obj[node].tmp_conf_list.end() )
        //        return false;
    }
    return true;
    // return false;
}
```

that makes a segmentation fault whenever I call it

```
void Graph::otherfunction() {
  if( termination_condition() == true )
    return 1;
}
```

what could be the problem?

Thanks

UPDATE:

```
int Graph::otherfunction() {
  if( termination_condition() == true )
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Where's `nodes` declared? Why all the commented out code in `termination_condition`?

Comment: `otherfunction` won't even compile, you can't `return 1;` from a `void` function.

Comment: @Charles: Commenting out large swaths of code is a reasonable way of narrowing down where a crash is occurring.

Comment: Also, `if (... == true)` is really silly.

Comment: **Nobody** expects segmentation fault! Its chief weapon is surprise... surprise and fear...fear and surprise. Its *two* weapons are fear and surprise...and ruthless efficiency.... Its *three* weapons are ...

Comment: @Ben otherfunction returns an int. I forgot to change it.  @Charles: nodes is declared within Graph

Comment: if I return false, there is no segmentation fault

Comment: @T.E.D.:  Missing a [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnQ_gIfgsnA), aren't you?

Comment: the program crashes when I return 1 from within otherfunction, I just checked. If I do not return anything the program will terminate with no segmentation fault, so I do not know what is happening

Answer (score 3):

My crystal ball says, the `this` pointer is NULL or otherwise invalid, and `nodes` is a member variable.

Answer (score 0):

With the little amount of information we've been given, all we can do is guess.

Your best bet is to hop into it with a debugger and find out where the problem is.  Setting a breakpoint at the start of `otherFunction` should be a good place to start.

Comment: I dunno. If he's munged the stack in some other routine and it just crashes there, a debuggger might not be much help.

Comment: True, but if he gets there and all his data is mangled, he'll know to look elsewhere.  A good starting point. :)